# How to configure Primefaces p:editor to enforce paragraphs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I'm using `p:editor` from primefaces (v.4.0)
Is there any way to setup the editor, so that every new line will be include in a `<p></p>` element ?

So far I've noticed that new lines are currently inserted with `<br />` or `<div>` or nothing at all (plain text), depending on the selected font style, or the client's browser!

Comment: Why not [`<pe:editor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf) instead?

Comment: @Tiny I'm working on integrating `<pe:editor>` right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrimeFaces uses [CLEditor](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/editor/editor.js#L3), and in that editor the line break is produced automatically by the Browser not CLEditor, because the iframe is in [designMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.designMode).

In IE  `<p>` is included unless a `<div>` was started. On all the others it's `<div>`.

You should provide that consistency in the back-end, by replacing each `<div>` with `<p>`

Read more:

- [Rich-Text Editing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)

Comment: testing with firefox, I can see that sometimes my source (html) text is not even contained in a `<div>`

Comment: Well, I ended up wrapping everything in `<div>`, conditionally,  in the backing Bean. But you covered up pretty much everything with your answer, so i'm Accepting. Thanx